# Implementing Interstitials using Admob Plugin in Unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, unityscript, interstitial

I am trying to implement Interstitials with Admob Plugin in Unity 4.6 and its a requirement to stick to the current scheme and achieve this target.

**What is Happening**

I have tried many things but unable to get the interstials work with Admob Plugin. I am using [this](https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin) Plugin. As the whole application is built on this plugin so I cant use another or new plugin.

Any Tutorial, Video Link or Code Snippet would be appreciated.